# Accessing a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this problem for quite a while now.

I am defining an array using the following:

```
  let newJsonObject = {
    "billing_name": document.getElementsByName("order[billing_name]")[0].value,
    "email": document.getElementsByName("order[email]")[0].value, 
  };
```

I get the data from storage and keep it in a variable named `parsedJson`, then do the three following `console.log` operations:

```
  console.log(parsedJson);
  console.log(parsedJson.billing_name);
  console.log(parsedJson["billing_name"]);
```

This first returns an object with the following:

```
parameters:
{"billing_name": "123", "email": "123"}
```

However, the following two things logged in the console are `undefined`.

I have also tried to create the object with the keys not having quotations, but I am still getting undefined

I don't understand why the log is returning null when the object is defined. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:
Here is how I am storing the data:

```
  chrome.storage.sync.set({"parameters": JSON.stringify(newJsonObject)});
```

Here is how I am accessing it:

```
  chrome.storage.sync.get("parameters", params => {
    if(params === null){
      //Nothing is even set, simply return
      return;
    }else{
      //Actually data saved in params
      let parsedJson = params;
      console.log(parsedJson);
      console.log(parsedJson.parameters.billing_name);
      console.log(parsedJson["billing_name"]);
```

[Here is a link to what is displayed in console](https://gyazo.com/a0a89ff19452ec43d3d15a970d8d35be)

Comment: can you say what you are getting by executing this `console.log(parsedJson.parameters);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `JSON.parse` converts your json string to object

try this

```
console.log(JSON.parse(parsedJson.parameters).billing_name);
```

Comment: What I am doing is taking my newJsonObject variable, stringifying it, then putting it into storage, when I access it, it comes out as an object. If I try JSON.parse, I receive an error: unexpected token o.

Comment: This worked for me! I guess the when you pull an object from chrome.storage.sync, it returns it as an object with an object attached to it. Thank you, I guess I should also name my variables better in the future!

Comment: You beat me with few sec. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var test = JSON.parse(parsedJson.parameters);
console.log(test.billing_name);
```

this will work.

Comment: It still returns undefined for me.

Comment: Your right! Thank you for the help, unfortunately, I saw Arun's post earlier so I accepted his answer. Nonetheless, I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @Jimmy Anytime!